# Проверка на нажатие кнопки php

Tags: php, html

Есть скрипт,который отправляет статистику о посещениях сайта в админ-панель

```
     <?php
       function countryCityFromIP($ipAddr)
       {
       $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];


       $url = "http://api.ipinfodb.com/v3/ip-city/?
   key=c28b69b0c7cb56b5d876f24a22529b43f9371d72bbf860e56f80a859dea1b878&ip=$ip&for
       mat=json";
       $d = file_get_contents($url);
       return json_decode($d , true);
       }
       $ip=countryCityFromIP($_REQUEST['ip']);

       //print_r($ip);

        $uri = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
        $dtime = date("F j, Y, g:i:s ");
       if($uri = "index.php"){
        $uri = "Зашел на сайт";
        }
        $ipp=$ip['ipAddress'];
        $ippp=$ip['countryName'];
        $ipppp=$ip['cityName'];
       if ($ippp == "Russian Federation") {
        $ippp = "RF";
        }
        if ($ippp == "United States") {
        $ippp = "US";
        }
        if (isset($_GET['button'])) {
        $uri = "Нажал кнопку";
        }
        $entry_line = "<center><table><tr><th><b>$dtime </b></th><th>
        <b>$ipp($ippp, $ipppp)</b></th><th><b> $uri </b></th></tr></table>
        </center>";

        $fp = fopen("admin/admin.php", "a");
        fputs($fp, $entry_line);
        fclose($fp);
        ?>
```

Есть кнопка,нужно,чтобы при нажатии на эту кнопку,значение переменной менялось

```
    <button  class="zakaz" data-zal="1" href="formpay.html" style="margin-
    top:20px">Заказать ОНЛАЙН</button>
```

Пробовал

```
     if (isset($_GET['button'])) {
     $uri = "Нажал кнопку";
     }
```

но не помогло

Comment: Shulga цитата: _Теоретически, тег <button> должен располагаться внутри формы, устанавливаемой элементом <form>. Тем не менее, браузеры не выводят сообщение об ошибке и корректно работают с тегом <button>, если он встречается самостоятельно. Однако, если необходимо результат нажатия на кнопку отправить на сервер, помещать <button> в контейнер <form> обязательно._

Comment: Покажи, пожалуйста, всю форму. Ответ ниже сейчас напишу, как понимаю, ты не совсем понимаешь саму функцию отправки формы.

Comment: <div class="">
                         <h3>Между нами горы</h3>
                        <span>Аренда зала - <strike>2200</strike><br> 1299 
                         RUB</span><br>
                         <span>От 1 до 8 человек</span><br>
                        <button  class="zakaz" data-zal="1" href="formpay.html" 
                        style="margin-top:20px">Заказать ОНЛАЙН</button>
                         </div>

Answer (score 0):

Html:

```
<form action="/formpay.html" method="get">
  <button class="zakaz" type="submit" name="button" data-zal="1" style="margin-top:20px">Заказать ОНЛАЙН</button>
</form>
```

Php остается тем же. Но вопрос - что ты хочешь по нажатию на кнопку?

Помни, что php - это язык backend'a, поэтому если по клику на кнопку, ты хочешь увидеть определенное модальное окно - используй js.

Comment: у меня не работает это

Comment: Значит, ты делаешь что-то не так. Напиши, пожалуйста, полностью вопрос. Покажи полный html, что ты хочешь добиться в итоге и т.д., короче говоря, отредактируй вопрос, ибо это нечитаемо и дать ответ, который будет более полный, чем мой, не получится.

Comment: отредактировал вопрос

Comment: при нажатии на кнопку открывается окно оплаты.

Comment: Ну так что мне делать???